# Parallax backgrounds in OpenGL ES on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, scroll, background

I've got basically a 2d game on the iPhone and I'm trying to set up multiple backgrounds that scroll at different speeds (known as parallax backgrounds).

So my thought was to just stick the backgrounds BEHIND the foreground using different z-coordinate planes, and just make them bigger than the foreground (in size) to accommodate, so that the whole thing can be scrolled (just at a different speed).

And (as far as I know) I basically implemented that.  The only problem is that it seems to entirely ignore whatever z-value I give it, or rather it just zeroes all of them.  I see the background (I've only tested ONE background so far, to keep it simple...so for now I just have a foreground and I want one background scrolling at a different speed), but it scrolls 1:1 with my foreground, so it obviously doesn't look right, and most of it is cut off (cause it's bigger).  And I've tried various z-values for the background and various near/far clipping planes...it's always the same.  I'm probably just doing one simple thing wrong, but I can't figure it out.  I'm wondering if it has to do with me using only 2 coordinates in glVertexPointer for the foreground? (Of course for the background I AM passing in 3)

I'll post some code:

This is some initial setup:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrthof(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.5f, 1.5f, -10.0f, 10.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
//glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

//transparency
glEnable (GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc (GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

A little bit about my foreground's float array....it's interleaved.  For my foreground it goes vertex x, vertex y, texture x, texture y, repeat.  This all works just fine.

This is my FOREGROUND rendering:

```
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 4*sizeof(GLfloat), texes); <br>
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 4*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)texes + 2*sizeof(GLfloat)); <br>
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, indexCount / 4);
```

BACKGROUND rendering:

Same drill here except this time it goes vertex x, vertex y, vertex z, texture x, texture y, repeat.  Note the z value this time.  I did make sure the data in this array was correct while debugging (getting the right z values).  And again, it shows up...it's just not going far back in the distance like it should.

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 5*sizeof(GLfloat), b1Texes);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 5*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)b1Texes + 3*sizeof(GLfloat));
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, b1IndexCount / 5);
```

And to move my camera, I just do a simple glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0f);

I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong cause this seems like the most basic 3D function imaginable...things further away are smaller and don't move as fast when the camera moves.  Not the case for me.  Seems like it should be pretty basic and not even really be affected by my projection and all that (though I've even tried doing glFrustum just for fun, no success).  Please help, I feel like it's just one dumb thing.  I will post more code if necessary.

Comment: Have you enabled depthBuffering?

Comment: For adding a depthbuffer see here http://www.memention.com/blog/2009/10/08/Think-deep.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that I am using orthographic projections which are incapable of displaying things being further away (please correct me if I'm wrong on this).  When I tried glFrustum earlier (as I stated in my question), I was doing something wrong with the setup of it.  I was using a negative value for the near-clipping value, and I basically got the 1:1 scrolling problem, same as orthographic.  But I have changed this to 0.01, and it finally started displaying correctly (backgrounds displayed further away).

My issue is resolved but just as a side idea, I'm now wondering if I can mix orthographic and perspective within the same frame, and what that would require.  Because I'd rather keep the foreground very simple and orthographic (2d), but I want my backgrounds to display with the perspective depth.

My idea was something like:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrthof(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.5f, 1.5f, -10.0f, 10.0f);

//render foreground

glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.5f, 1.5f, 0.01f, 1000.0f);

//render backgrounds
```

I will play around with this and comment with my results, in case anyone is curious.  Feedback on this would be appreciated, though technically I have no pressing need on this issue anymore (from here on out it would just be idea discussion).

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark...

You may have to forgotten to setup the Depth-Buffering within the framebuffer initializer.

Copy&Paste from Apple's older EAGLView templates:

```
    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
```

Comment: I am actually using this template.  I'm testing on an iPhone OS 2.2.1, and I have the SDK 3.0 or something.  The code you have written there is embedded in an "if (USE_DEPTH_BUFFER)" statement, and I do have USE_DEPTH_BUFFER #define'd as 1.  I also debugged and made sure that code is getting called.  Still stumped but thanks for the suggestion.  Am I forgetting a glEnable of something?

Answer (score 0):

If you are depending of blending you must draw in depth order, meaning draw the furthest (deepest) layer first. Otherwise they will be covered by the layer on top as the z-buffer value is written even though the area is 100% transparent.

See [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting)